# Remove circle drawn in html5 canvas once user clicks on it

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, onclick, html5-canvas

I wrote a code that generates randomly 60 circles in a canvas, how do I handle that an event `onclick` circle pressed disappear and after is generated another?
which may be the best solution?
the code is:

```
var canvas, ctx;
var circles = [];
var selectedCircle;
var vel=200;    

function Circle(x, y, radius){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}

function clear() { // clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius) {

    var color = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function generate(){

    canvas = document.getElementById('my');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var circleRadius = 25;
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var timer, j = 0;

    var circlesCount = 60;
    for (var i=0; i<circlesCount; i++) {
        var x = Math.random()*width;
        var y = Math.random()*height;    
        circles.push(new Circle(x,y,circleRadius));
    }

    timer = window.setInterval(function()

    {
        if(j==60)
        {
            clear();
            return;
        }
        drawCircle(ctx, circles[j].x, circles[j].y, circles[j].radius);
        // go to next circle
        j++;
    }, vel);
}
```

Comment: Your circles are overlapping on other circles. How are you going to clear it?

Comment: yes,how can I not overlapping circles and  to click delele the circle?

Comment: how about saving all positions of generated circles into an array and then check (calculate) it before drawing new circle .

Comment: ok,and fot the event onclick to delete the circle? help me with the code please

Comment: nothing? help  me please

Comment: you cannot use abusive language here!!

Comment: @AngeloSolla, Have a look over this [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32736999/revisions). Let me know which revision makes more sense ? And which title proves **stupidity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **best** solution for this IMO would be to use svg, which will create SVGElements, each one with it's own events interface.

Now, it's not impossible to do it with a canvas, but as mentioned by @VickyGonsalves, you'll have to store all circles positions, calculate their superficy and check if the click event's clientX and clientY are inside one of them, then redraw the whole without the ones being clicked.

However, the new [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) interface, allows to store paths and reuse them later, or use them into context's methods such as `fill()` and `isPointInPath()`.

So here is a simple solution using the `Path2d()` constructor, which [is supported 
neither by IE, nor by Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D#Browser_compatibility).

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  circles = [];
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

function Circle(x, y, radius) {
  var c = new Path2D();
  c.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  return c;
}

function init() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    circles.push(Circle((Math.random() * (canvas.width - 40)) + 20, (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 40)) + 20, 20));
    ctx.fill(circles[i], "nonzero");
    ctx.stroke(circles[i], "nonzero");
  }
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = e.clientX - r.left,
    y = e.clientY - r.top,
    i;

  for (i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    console.log(i);
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(circles[i], x, y, 'nonzero')) {
      circles.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    ctx.fill(circles[i], "nonzero")
    ctx.stroke(circles[i], "nonzero");
  }
}
canvas.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
init();
```